# How to export a crystal report data to excel in tabular format when report is not in tabular format

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report with data in the following format.

```
---------------------------------------

Name    : xxxx              Age     : xxxx
Surname : xxxx              Address : xxxx
DOB     : xxxx              Points  : xxxx

----------------------------------------
```

If I export the report and data to Excel I get the similar layout.

However, I want the data in tabular format (like below) that is
the first row will contain headers and the subsequent contain data

```
Name    Surname     DOB     Age     Address     Points
xxxx    xxxx        xxxx    xxxx    xxxx        xxxx
xxxx    xxxx        xxxx    xxxx    xxxx        xxxx
xxxx    xxxx        xxxx    xxxx    xxxx        xxxx
```

Is it possible to achieve this **without changing the current layout of the report**.

I know that I can changing the layout and design to tabular format but the columns are many.

Can I do this in `code` if so please assist. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Crystal also offers an Excel (Data Only) export format. 
That would indeed produce a tabular layout.

Comment: Thanks much, It will indeed produce a tabular format with headers in their own columns. For example the first row would contain something like this `name,surname,DOB, Age,Address,Points,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx` the second row would be the same with the xxxx being replaced by the second record. In such a case the user will need to do additional task of removing other columns and assigning headers manually.